# How to simulate a Socket with SocketTImeoutException for JUnit test?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a service that connects to a socket. I want to create an integration test that tests `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`.

For not having to mock in detail, I simply want to launch a local socket server during the `junit` test, and send the requests to this local socket.

```
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass(){
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345, 0, InetAddress.getByName(null));

    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.run();
}

@Test
public void testSocket() {
    myservice.send();
}
```

Problem: the code above blocks when I connect to that test socket. How can I here simulate a `SocketTimeoutException` and not block the test execution?

Comment: One option is to use a mocking framework, such as Mockito, to mock whichever method you want and force it to throw a `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: Sounds weird. An integration test that tests...low level socket functionality? Did you set a socket timeout?

Comment: Why simulate? Why not use a real socket?

Answer (score 1):

I clould solve it as follows (when using `spring-integration` for the socket connection):

```
@MockBean
private AbstractClientConnectionFactory fac;

given(fac.getConnection()).willThrow(new UncheckedIOException(new SocketTimeoutException("test")));
```